# How is props passed in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am trying to understand how Props work in React. The following code is giving an error - `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {args})`

```
const App = () => {
  const course = 'Half Stack application development'

  return (
      <div>
        <Header args={course}/> // Will an object be passed or just the string?
      </div>
  )
}

const Header = (agrs)=>{
    console.log(agrs)
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>{agrs}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

1. When props are being passed, is an Object is passed encapsulating the fields or just the field values are passed?
2. why does the above code doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: you are missing react import.

Comment: The error message tells you why the code doesn't work. What do you expect the line `<h1>{agrs}</h1>` to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you have a spelling mistake. Replace `agrs` with `args`. Secondly, props are passed as an object (dictionary), so you have one of two options:

```js
const Header = (props) =>{
    console.log(props.args)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.args}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

or [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const Header = ({args}) =>{
    console.log(args)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{args}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also, make sure to add props validation (your linter should warn you about this):

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

Header.propTypes = {
  args: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: Value is passed as a key with the same name as field you assigned it to in props object.

Answer 2:

```
const Header = (props)=>{
    console.log(props.agrs)
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>{props.agrs}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The code above will run fine.

Alternative to answer 2:

```
const Header = ({agrs})=>{
    console.log(agrs)
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>{agrs}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This will also run fine.
It uses object destructuring so you don't have to use props.agrs but just args works fine.

Comment: if field is passed then the value of prop inside the Header is =  'Half Stack application development'. Then why do I need to do props.args?

Comment: By field I meant value and not variable or reference. I will edit my answer for clarity

Answer (score 1):

```
const App = () => {
  const course = 'Half Stack application development'

  return (
      <div>
        <Header args={course}/> // Will an object be passed or just the string?
      </div>
  )
}

const Header = ({agrs})=>{
    console.log(agrs)
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>{agrs}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Use object Destructuring like above or

```
const Header = (props)=>{
        console.log(props.agrs)
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>{props.agrs}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Find more here [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).
Find more about [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: is 'props' is the keyword which has to be used? Can't I change it to args or Something

Comment: yes , the component receives an object, which you can destructure to get the values

Answer (score 0):

```
        import React from 'react';

    class App extends React.Component {
       render() {
          return (
             <div>
                <h1>{this.props.headerProp}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.contentProp}</h2>
             </div>
          );
       }
    }
    export default App;


import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App headerProp = "Header from props..." contentProp = "Content
   from props..."/>, document.getElementById('app'));

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhMeV.png)